# How to quickly change DNS servers as needed (instead of manually changing) on Windows

Tags: linux, windows, dns

My country (Turkey) is blocking almost all adult-content-containing websites.

I can work around this by changing the DNS, but it's too much work :) Any alternatives? Or a way to quickly change (and reset) my DNS?

Comment: Whoever edited this, thank you so much for wording it so smoothly. Although I remember adding the request especially for being able to post in 4chan. Can we put it back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quickly switch DNS you should first identify the name of your network interface.

Go to Control Panel and search for "View Network Connections" and then find the name of the one that you use to connect to the internet.  It is often convenient to rename the connection from "Local Area Connection" to something easier to type.

Then create two batch files like below (replace "Local Area Connection" to the name you found in the previous step:

```
REM Set DNS to Google
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Local Area Connection" static 8.8.8.8 primary
ipconfig /flushdns
```

And:

```
REM Set DNS to whatever
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Local Area Connection" static x.x.x.x primary
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Alternatively, the following will reset DNS to the one provided by your DHCP:

```
REM Set DNS to DHCP
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Local Area Connection" dhcp
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Then just run them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! However, I remember having some problems with flushdns before. Can you confirm this has no -risks of- problems? Also, this is for Windows, right? That's cool because I'm looking for a solution for Windows 8.1, but I would also like to see another (or a cross-OS) solution for Linux too.

Comment: Hi, I don't know what problems you had with flush dns but it's a pretty standard command that works.

Yes this is a .bat file in windows. I made the assumption you were using Windows as you didn't provide the name of your Linux distro.

Comment: Dear Jay, can you please provide (for the 2nd script) that reverts to default DNS?

Comment: I can't edit my previous comment.. @Jay thank you so much. Resetting to DHCP is what I was looking for. I will try this now and accept if it's working. **Edit :** It works, but one strange detail, when I use the first one (change DNS to Google) then I'm able to open 4chan. But when I run the 3rd script to revert back to DHCP (I checked manually, the DNS changes in both cases) but I'm still be able to open 4chan. Is this related to browser cache or something? Anyway, you answered my question so I'm accepting your answer. But I would appreciate additional explanation :) Thanks again !

Comment: For future users, don't forget to run these .bat files as administrator. Also, how do I set a batch file do run as admin. when I double click?

Comment: Right click on the .bat file. Go to properties > Compatability > and check always run as administrator.